# In Drone 0.5, is it possible to apply a matrix to only certain pipeline steps?

Tags: drone.io

I have a [matrix](http://readme.drone.io/0.5/usage/build-matrix/) in my drone.yml, but it only should run on one of my pipeline steps.  Is it possible to only apply the matrix to certain steps?

For example, I do not want the matrix to apply on the `publish` step:

```
pipeline:
  test:
    image: ruby
    commands:
      - bundle exec rspec ${TESTFOLDER}
  publish:
    image: ruby
    commands:
      - magic-publish

matrix:
  TESTFOLDER:
    - integration/user
    - integration/shopping_cart
    - integration/payments
    - units
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to "magic-publish" only once, you might want to restrict it to a single element of your matrix (maybe the last one):

```
when:
  matrix:
    TESTFOLDER: units
```

You could also attach the deployment step to a `tag` or `deploy` event.

cf. [How to setup conditional build steps](http://readme.drone.io/0.5/usage/conditional-build-steps/)

Comment: Excellent - I did not realize I could do a conditional on a matrix value!